# Store large frequently accessed data, InnoDB?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I have a lot (5m) of images and I decided for security reasons (corruption protection and COMMITs) to use a MySQL database to store them. Those images will be accessed pretty frequently, 100 per second. Most of them will be about 10kb or less (95%), but a few can be 100kb or more.

The above makes my life a pain because not all images fit in the `VARCHAR` limit, and I am forced to use `TEXT`.

From what I understand the database stores the 1st 768 bytes on page and the rest off page. This seems a pretty good idea for the average db out there, but I need to access those `TEXT` too frequently. **How can I force the database to store everything on page?**

Comment: Don't store images in a database: store them in the filesystem, and only store a filepath in the database.... if you absolutely have to store images in a database, you shouldn't be using either VARCAHR or TEXT, but BLOB

Comment: Yes, but those images will be edited by the user. I need to use the COMMIT system. Okay, BLOB is basically TEXT without charset, so my post is still valid.

Comment: So why does that preclude storing them in the filesystem?

Comment: I want to update the images only when 100 images are edited. If 99 images are edited and the system crashes I want the changes to revert back.

Comment: The answer to your question is "no".  Pages are too small for what you are storing, so data has to be stored on multiple pages. I don't know why this is a problem, though.

Comment: Everyone else is right, you really should be storing this on the filesystem.  But if you can't I think you could theoretically use TokuDB for this, it wouldn't break up the rows like InnoDB would, and 100 reads/sec is pretty much what you'll get off a single disk.  It should work.  You could also add more drives in RAID to get more disk seeks if you stick with InnoDB.  You may want to turn off compression if the images are already compressed, but YMMV and you should probably just test it and see.  (disclaimer: I work at Tokutek)

Comment: Please see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21513000/will-this-be-stored-on-page/21716805#21716805 There is no way to tell InnoDB what store in the index page what store in external pages. But there is a rule. If record size is less than 7k then the record will be stored in the index page.